# neo4j org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException with authentication-extension plugin

Tags: java, neo4j

The server started fine without the plugin. Then I stopped it, and followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/authentication-extension) using the latest version (2.1.5-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar).

When I try to start ne04j, I get a org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException:

```
    2014-12-22 14:15:41.817+0000 DEBUG [API]
    org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j Server failed: Found class org.neo4j.server.database.Database, but interface was      expected
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:211) ~[neo4j-server-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
        at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:86) [neo4j-server-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
        at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:49) [neo4j-server-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
    Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class org.neo4j.server.database.Database, but interface was expected
        at org.neo4j.server.extension.auth.AuthenticationExtensionInitializer.start(AuthenticationExtensionInitializer.java:78) ~[authentication- extension-2.1.5-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.5-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.neo4j.server.modules.ExtensionInitializer.initializePackages(ExtensionInitializer.java:60) ~[neo4j-server-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
        at org.neo4j.server.modules.ThirdPartyJAXRSModule.start(ThirdPartyJAXRSModule.java:61) ~[neo4j-server-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.startModules(AbstractNeoServer.java:254) ~[neo4j-server-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:185) ~[neo4j-server-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
        ... 2 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using? Your stacktrace shows 1.9.4 classes as well as 2.1.5 from the auth extension.

Comment: "1.9.4", I'll try the older auth builds. Thanks!